# How to change language on Opera snap on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snap, language-support, opera, can

How to change language on Opera snap on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal then do `snap set opera env=LANG=<language_code>`

replace language_code by the one you want, you can find all your available language with this:

```
snap run --shell opera
ls /snap/opera/current/usr/share/locale/
```